# B1/B2 visa. Why did I have to sign a form after a random search?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, airports

Why a random search while departing and boarding a plane in the United States? I was selected randomly for a search, asking how much money I was traveling with, and how long I stayed in the USA. I stayed four months but I was flying with only 350 USD.

I’m not worried but curious because it was my second time traveling and I saw a lot of us selected randomly.

The form asked for my name, how long I stayed and if I had less than 10,000 USD.

I think it was CPB officers because they had a wireless handheld device doing air biometric exit .

Comment: no-one can answer without a lot more details. Who searched you? Were they customs or immigration people, or security? If you had to sign a form, what did it say, what were you agreeing to? Please add more details to the question.

Comment: Name, how long i stayed, how much money

Comment: I don’t remember who they were whether customs or immigration but they were at the plane while we were boarding onto the flight

Comment: Was it this form? https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/customs-declaration-6059b.jpg

Comment: No it wasn’t. It was a white paper with like 3/4 questions.  Now i feel nervous cause no one knows this form . A friend of mind said she always have to signed it after being randomly searched

Comment: I haven't seen the form in question, but CBP is testing biometric exit checks at some airports, and they enforce the law that those carrying more than $10,000 in cash or cash equivalents have to declare it. I would imagine, sight unseen, that the form simplifies the process for them: if they catch you lying, they have a written document to demonstrate it, and you can't claim you didn't understand the rules or the question.

Comment: Thanks Zach . Well he did state I wasn’t in trouble and asked if it was my first visit . But do you think that will affect my next trip to the usa ?

Comment: @BrotanyWatson extremely unlikely. They're just spot checking people to see whether they're in compliance with customs and immigration requirements. You were in compliance, so there should be no adverse consequences.

Comment: Thabk you . Really appreciate all this

Comment: Ooh, sorry for.misspelling your name :(